# How to pass extra options to OpenBSD's EFI boot loader with systemd-boot?

Tags: uefi, openbsd, systemd-boot

I have an extra `systemd-boot` entry for OpenBSD.

```
 $ cat /boot/loader/entries/bsd.conf
title OpenBSD
efi /extra/bootx64.efi
```

It works and I manage to get into `boot` shell,

The problem is that by default it tries to boot from `hd0`,
I need it to boot from `hd1`, which I have to specify manually with

```
> set device hd1
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
 $ cat /boot/loader/entries/bsd.conf
title OpenBSD
efi /extra/bootx64.efi
options set device hd1a # it does not work
```

Is there a way to pass `hd1` as a parameter to `bootx64.efi`, without typing it manually?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-boot#Configuration might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `set device hd1a` in your `/etc/boot.conf` on your OpenBSD `a` partition.